# Get only numbers in version from dll file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wmic

I'm trying to get the vertion of a .dll file, but only the number of the version.

I find the code

```
wmic datafile where name='C:\\...\\MY_FILE.dll' get version
```

This code returns:

```
Version
3.56.0.1
```

I need the return to be only '3.56.0.1' and this could be saved in a variable for i'll can call in a echo after.

```
set var="HOW DO I DO?"
echo %var%
```

How can I get this?

I can use the code below too, but in this format I think its harder

```
wmic datafile where name='C:\\...\\MY_FILE.dll' get version /format:list
```

This code returns:

```
Version=3.56.0.1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And similarly to those posted, with minor differences.

A [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```bat
@For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('WMIC DataFile Where "Name='C:\\...\\MY_FILE.dll'" Get Version /Value 2^>Nul')Do @For /F "Tokens=*" %%B In ("%%A")Do @Set "%%B"
@Echo(%Version%&Pause
```

A [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) version:

```bat
For /F "Delims=" %A In ('WMIC DataFile Where "Name='C:\\...\\MY_FILE.dll'" Get Version /Value 2^>Nul')Do @For /F "Tokens=*" %B In ("%A")Do @Set "%B"
```

Where the variable `%Version%` should be `set` to the local environment.

Answer (score 2):

So you would require a for loop to do this.. see more help on it by running `for /?` from `cmd.exe`

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%i in ('wmic datafile where name^="C:\\...\\MY_FILE.dll" get version /format:list') do if not defined var set var=%%j
echo %var%
```

Note that the help will not assist you with the caret escape character used on the `=` which however you can find help on here at SO.

Answer (score 2):

- You'll need to parse with a `for /f`.
- And another `for /f` to repair broken WMIC output.

On cmdline (using a windows dll):

```
For /f "usebackqdelims=" %A in (`wmic datafile where name^='C:\\Windows\\System32\\authui.dll' get version /format:list^|findstr "Version"`) do @For /F "delims=" %B in ("%A") do @Set "%B"
set Version
Version=10.0.17134.1
```

In a batch file double the percent signs of the for meta variable(s)

Comment: Waffles with my answer. Exactly the same time posted :). No need to use a `for /F` loop, a single `for` would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```bat
@echo off

for /F "delims== tokens=2" %%A IN ('wmic datafile where name^="C:\\...\\MY_FILE.dll" get version /format:list') do (
    for %%B IN ("%%A") do set "var_name=%%~B"
)
echo %var_name%
```

which loops through your command and finds the second token according to the delimeter specified (`=`).

Due to `wmic` unusual line endings (`<CR><CR><LF>`), you should use a double `for` loop.

Comment: Two `for` loops to get a version from a variable?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I have explained what is the difference and why I am doing it.

Comment: what I am saying is it is unneeded, why 2 loops, you kick of an additional process to find just the version. You specificallt say you should use a double for loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you scripted in PowerShell, you could use:

```
$var = [Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo('C:/.../MY_FILE.dll').ProductVersion
```

If you want to do it in a .bat file script, there is some overhead.

```
C:>TYPE gv.bat
@ECHO OFF

FOR /F "delims=" %%v IN ('PowerShell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "[Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo('C:/Windows/System32/dfscli.dll').ProductVersion"') DO (
    SET "var=%%~v"
)
ECHO var is +++%var%+++

C:>CALL gv.bat
var is +++10.0.17763.1+++
```